# Background color an extended table column that does not have rows filled

Tags: html, css, background-color

I have a table that is extended, but only has two rows of data. I would like to color the background of the first **column** all the way to the bottom of the page, but am not sure to do that especially because there are no rows extending the table. Not sure if there is a way to do this, but would appreciate any help.

Here is the JS Fiddle: jsfiddle.net/5E24f/
I would like the background color of column 1 to extend to the bottom of the page.

Comment: What do you mean by "rows extending the table?" Can you show us an example, possibly on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: I'm sure there is a way to do this, but would appreciate any HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way you could possibly do that is if you know exactly how wide your first column will be.

http://jsfiddle.net/5E24f/4/

```
table.patientinfo:after {
    content: " ";
    background: orange; /* replace with your bg color */
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 17px; /* matches the width of your first column */
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have my table inside a floated right container. Right now it is stuck to the left of my screen. What would be the best way to get it under the table? Thanks!

Comment: That *really* complicates things.  Add `position: relative` to the floated container.  You might want to attach the above code to the parent container (or floated container) instead of the table.